# Is there a way to load a PHP function into an iframe?

Tags: php

I know this might not be a very good technique, but please understand what I want to do and help me out in doing exactly what I want to do.

I have created an iframe, in a PHP file, and I have a bunch of functions, each use the echo command to echo out text and HTML to the screen. I want to call the PHP function (that echoes) into an iframe, so it takes the contents of the PHP function (the echo) and prints it to the iframe (rendering the HTML and text in the iframe).

How would I do that?

Comment: PHP code executes at the server before the HTML of the page is sent to the browser. There is no iframe at this point. If you want to change what's inside an iframe after the page has loaded, then you need to use JavaScript. That JavaScript can make HTTP requests to your PHP scripts (AJAX) to get text to use...

Comment: you can use a `get` variable that selects a particular function from the list of functions in functions.php and `exit(1);` after the required content is echoed. Or you could use a separate file ...

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't "do that".

An iframe needs to load its' contents from a separate document. Albeit, its' possible to create an iframe with contents in client side scripting, but not server side.